# New to R, my code seems to be executing if statements when it should not

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm new to R coding, and the below is my first real R code. I asked a similar question yesterday, and now hopefully have what is considered to be a minimal reproducible example. I have run this code and examined the variables and found that when I have a text file with one sheet number such as "6202 1 4 5 7 10" it works. But when I have variables with 2 sheet numbers such as "6401 1 6202 5" it does not work. To run this code you have to make text files with that text in them.

It seems the If statement in the while loop is not working properly. It seems to not execute if there is a second variable of over 1000 value. At least it does not create or assign that variable to tmpvarname2. I have tried changing the code to "tmpvarname2 < parameters[pcount]" and that does not work either.

Please note that I am new here, new to R and I am autistic, so please keep your responses related to the code, and not to me as an individual.

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning=F, message=F, fig.pos='H', fig.align='center')
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')
```

### Summary

This code is designed to read in a text file containing 2 or more numbers, separated by spaces. The first number should be a 4 digest Australian Bureau of Statistics (ABS) data table number. The remaining digits should be table numbers. For example; 6202 1 4
It should then download the ABS tables, tidy them up and output them as a spreadsheet with the name of the ABS spreadsheet and table number/s.

### Load requisite R libaries

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(readabs)
library(xlsx)
```

```
parameters <- c(read.delim(file.choose(), header=FALSE, sep=' '))
listlength <- length(parameters)

sncount <- 1
tncount <-1

if(listlength>0) {
    if (parameters[1]>=1000){
    sn1 <- parameters[1]
    listlength <- listlength-1
    sncount <- 2
    }
}

if (parameters[2]<=99){
    tn1 <- parameters[2]
    T1 <- paste("S",sn1,"T",parameters[2],sep = "")
    listlength <- listlength-1
    tncount <- 2
}
 
spreadsheetfilename <- paste(sn1, "T", tn1, ".xlsx", sep ="") 

testsheet <- read_abs(sn1, tables=c(tn1)) %>% select(date, value, series_id) %>% pivot_wider(names_from=series_id, values_from=value, values_fn=list(value=mean))

 write.xlsx2(testsheet, file=spreadsheetfilename, sheetName=T1, col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE)

pcount <- 3  

if (listlength==0) {
  quit(save = "no")
}

while(listlength>0) {

  ## This is the part that does not work correctly. It seems to be doing the first if statement even if the parameter is greater than 99.

  if ((parameters[pcount])<=99){
    tmpvarname2 <- assign(paste("tn", tncount, sep = ""),parameters[pcount])
    tmpvarname3 <- assign(paste("T", tncount, sep = ""),paste("S",sn1,"T",parameters[pcount],sep = ""))
   tncount <- tncount +1
     listlength <- listlength-1
  pcount <- pcount +1
   } else { tmpvarname1 <- assign(paste("sn", sncount, sep = ""),parameters[pcount])
   sncount <- sncount +1
     listlength <- listlength-1
  pcount <- pcount +1
  } 
  
 testsheet <- read_abs(sn1, tables=c(tmpvarname2)) %>% select(date, value, series_id) %>% pivot_wider(names_from=series_id, values_from=value, values_fn=list(value=mean))

 write.xlsx2(testsheet, file=spreadsheetfilename, sheetName=tmpvarname3, col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=TRUE)
}
```

---

#### Gregor's attempt at a minimal example

```
parameters <- list(V1 = 6401L, V2 = 1L, V3 = 6202L, V4 = 5L)
sn1 <- parameters[1]
sncount <- 2
tn1 <- parameters[2]
T1 <- paste("S",sn1,"T",parameters[2],sep = "")
tncount <- 2

listlength <- 2
pcount <- 3  

while(listlength>0) {
  message(paste(
    "While loop iteration: list length =", listlength,
    "\n  parameters =", toString(parameters),
    "\n  pcount =", pcount
  ))
  if ((parameters[pcount])<=99){
    message("    if statement executing!")
    tncount <- tncount +1
    listlength <- listlength-1
    pcount <- pcount +1
  } else { 
   message("    else statement executing!")
   sncount <- sncount +1
   listlength <- listlength-1
   pcount <- pcount +1
  } 
}
# While loop iteration: list length = 2 
#   parameters = 6401, 1, 6202, 5 
#   pcount = 3
#     else statement executing!
# While loop iteration: list length = 1 
#   parameters = 6401, 1, 6202, 5 
#   pcount = 4
#     if statement executing!
```

Comment: This is much better than your question yesterday, but it is nowhere close to minimal. Why do I need to create a text file? For the example, just set `parameters = c(6401, 1, 6202, 5)` in your code. If the problem is still there, then that's great--you don't need to read that vector from a text file to test it. If the problem disappears, then you've identified the source of the problem: your `read.delim()` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Would you please load the parameters file that doesn't work, and then run `dput(parameters)` and paste the result into your question? That will make a reproducible and copy/pasteable version of your non-working input, including all class and structure information. I'd also recommend deleting code that seems unrelated to the problem. Your test case has `listlength` of 4, I think, so the `if (listlength==0){...}` at least can be deleted.

Comment: At some point, I'd strongly recommend watching Jenny Bryan's fantastic talk [Object of type closure is not subsettable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgYS-F8opgE&t=1s). There's a lot of great concepts in there, but especially the usefulness of creating minimal reproducible examples, along with guidance on how to do it, is very well illustrated.

Comment: I'm going to attempt to edit your question to add a fairly minimal example at the bottom. What I did was run all your code before the `while` loop and then set all the variables as I found them right before the while loop. I deleted all the `tmpvarname` code as that doesn't have any impact on the while/if/else structure. I added some `message()` statements that will print a little bit of what the code is doing while it executes. What happens makes sense to me, so I'm hoping you can comment specifically on how you expect it to be different.

Comment: Thank you Gregor.
I changed the read text file to the parameters = c(6401, 1, 6202, 5)  in my code.
The result was the same. It still indicates that it can't find tmpvarname2
But when I change parameters = c(6401, 1, 3, 5)  the code works.

Comment: So I've pretty much eliminated an issue with reading in the parameters because in R Studio I can open and view what each variable is, and can see the parameters are correct as per the text file. 
The if (listlength==0){...} is needed for when I have a text file with just 2 parameters, a sheet and a table. The code is designed (well should be designed) to read in a text file of between 2 and many parameters.

Comment: *"The if (listlength==0){...} is needed for when I have a text file with just 2 parameters"*. Yes, of course. I'm not asking you to delete that from *your code* on *your computer*. I'm saying it's completely irrelevant to the problem in the `while` loop, so here on Stack Overflow it just clutters the question. When we ask for a **minimal** example,  we want you to isolate the problem. This both makes your question clearer **and** is a useful debugging technique in itself. 90% of the time (or more), if you make a minimal reproducible example, you'll solve your own problem.

Comment: The goal of **your code** is to read a text file and process it. The goal of **the question** is to fix the issue with the `if` statement in the `while` loop. In your code in your R file, you need all the stuff to process the text files appropriately. In the code you show us in this question, every line of code that isn't necessary to demonstrate the problem of the `if` statement in the `while` loop just makes this harder to tell what's going on. The goal **for the code in the question** should be to delete every line of code you possibly can while still demonstrating the problem.

Comment: But also please verify object classes. I don't know if your text files have the numbers in columns or rows. So I don't know if your `parameters` is a 1-row data frame or a numeric vector. So I don't know if a good test case is `parameters <- c(6401, 1, 6202, 5)` or `parameters <- list(V1 = 6401L, V2 = 1L, V3 = 6202L, V4 = 5L)` or `parameters <- data.frame(V1 = 6401L, V2 = 1L, V3 = 6202L, V4 = 5L)` or maybe something else. And I don't know if that matters--it might. So please be that exact in specifying the sample data.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel this way. I would say I'm trying to help you do things the Stack Overflow way--you are on Stack Overflow, after all. If you would really rather not try to do things the Stack Overflow way, then I think you're making a wise decision to seek alternatives rather than try to force Stack Overflow to do things your way.

Comment: If you have specific examples of where I've been unwelcoming, I'd be happy to hear the feedback. I've been trying my best to help you do things the Stack Overflow way, which is the best way I know to help people. I've answered 5 questions in the last day, and I've tried very hard to answer this one, but I don't know the answer with the information as you've provided it. I've actually spent more time trying to work with you to answer this question than I've spent on the other 5 questions I've answered since.

Comment: I'd also note that your first question showed little effort to do things the Stack Overflow way, and it got one downvote (though not from me... I rarely downvote questions). This question is showing effort, and it got no downvotes. I'd again strongly recommend that you watch the Jenny Bryan talk I linked above, I think it's a great video for any new coders. And as you've found the Stack Overflow way doesn't work for you, I sincerely hope you find the help you need elsewhere.